# pycharm ERROR: Package 'pandas' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.5.3'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

i can not use pandas library in pycharm. How can i solve?

my error message is:

pycharm ERROR: Package 'pandas' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.5.3'

thanks for your support.

Comment: You will need to install an older version of pandas(<2.5) or upgrade your python to a higher version. This github issue might help: 


   https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27558

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation of Pandas, if you want to use the latest version of Pandas (ver. 0.25) it supports "Officially Python 3.5.3 and above, 3.6, and 3.7."

So, you must upgrade at least from Python 3.5.2 to Python 3.5.3 in order to use the latest version of Pandas.

Or if you need Python 3.5.2, use Pandas ver. 0.24

info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#python-version-support

Answer (score 0):

first of all it's not a PyCharm error
it's a dependency error.
the error is saying that you need a version of python less than 3.5.3 to run your current pandas
but you the python version greater than 3.5.3

> try installing the latest version of pandas

```
pip install pandas==0.25.1
```

or downgrade your python version to the dependencies of your pandas current version

hope it works